# Attribute of a Django Model: Check for Usages on Production Systems

Tags: python, django, deprecation-warning

## Background

Imagine I have a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

I want to:

1. deprecate `name` and update all Python code which uses it.
2. remove the attribute

My guess: grep and PyCharm will only find 98% usages in the code, since "name" is used in a lot of other places.

## Question

I want to detect if code gets executed on production systems which use this attribute. Maybe like this:

```
OtherModel.objects.filter(foo__name=...)
```

Is there a way to log a DeprecationWarning if the a Model.objects.filter() call uses this attribute?

Then I can install the new code which logs the warning. If I see no warning for about 8 weeks I can be sure that no important part gets broken if I remove the attribute.

Comment: Would you like to completely remove this attribute or rename it? If you want to remove it, what do you want to do with the existing data? Remove them as well?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard three columns of this model will move to a new model, since the cardinality changed from 1:1 to 1:N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think doing this at Python/Django level would be very painful and almost impossible to make sure all cases are covered.

Best is probably to keep both fields for some time and use SQL triggers to:

1. Keep them synced
2. Raise a warning when the deprecated field is accessed

Answer (score 2):

### Unit Testing

This is when unit tests pay you back 10 fold for the effort you put into them. If you have high code coverage, just go ahead and delete the field. Then run the unit tests. It will quickly show you which lines of code you have to change.

### Using Properties.

Not so good as using unit tests. Doesn't work with Foo.models.filter() but works for the instances when you access the field in a model instance.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    _name=models.CharField(max_length=1024)



    @property
    def name(self):
        traceback.print_stack()
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        traceback.print_stack()
        self._name = value
```

Comment: We have tests. Coverage is not 100% but, but all important stuff gets tested. Each new bug gets a test since about three years. I follow the guideline: "hope is not an option". That's why I am curious if my idea can be implemented. Your solution and the one from Antoine (checking at SQL level) should get most errors.

Comment: 100% coverage is pretty hard to achieve but if you are right up there, you shouldn't have an trouble, specially if you combine the answers.

Comment: Note you can also override the `save()` method to handle the presence of 'name' in `update_fields` and eventually save a related model if `name` was relocated elsewhere.